# Adding border to multiple images using gimp?

Tags: imagemagick, editing, gimp

I have around 100 pictures that i want to add white border to it all at once.
I use Linux and also use gimp ,.. please suggest me something to do so online of offline.
and one more thing that i have tried convert option on imagemagick but nothing happen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to do 100 all at once you will be best off using ImageMagick's `mogrify` command like this to add a 10 pixel white border around all images:

```
mogrify -mattecolor white -frame 10x10 image*.jpg
```

If the images are not all in a single directory, you can do the following which will do the same thing across all subdirectories of the one you are currently in:

```
find . -name \*.jpg -exec convert "{}" -mattecolor white -frame 10x10 "{}" \;
```

Obviously you can change the `10` to a different number of pixels if you wish.

Please make a backup before using this as I may have misunderstood your needs.

**Updated**

If you want a drop shadow, you really need to be working with `PNG` rather than `JPG` since the former supports transparency and the latter doesn't - but IM can convert your JPEGs to PNGs anyway. I use the following command for drop shadows:

```
convert image.jpg \( -clone 0 -background black -shadow 80x3+0+8 \) -reverse -background none -layers merge +repage image.png
```

So, I would apply that to a pile of images like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.jpg; do
   new=${f%%jpg}png    # Work out new name = original name minus "jpg" + "png"
   echo Processing $f into $new
   convert "$f" \( -clone 0 -background black -shadow 80x3+0+8 \) -reverse -background none -layers merge +repage "$new"
done
```

Comment: thinks allot .... it worked.. previously  i tried this : convert -border 10x10 *.png  and got an error

Comment: Glad it worked out. In general, if you find yourself wanting to specify `*.jpg`, you probably need to be looking at `mogrify` rather than `convert`.

Comment: can you please tell me that how do i put shadow bellow them ??

Comment: Please have another look now.

Comment: thanks allot once again ... it worked again .... thankyou very much .... are you a image-processing specialist ?? or working in the same field..?

Comment: I'm a photographer (http://www.thesetchells.com) that spends too much time on the computer and not enough taking photos :-)

Comment: Thank-you very much for telling me your field of interest